# How to iterate through worksheets and AutoFilter by one column

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro that copies each sheet and saves it as a separate workbook, but at some point in the macro I need to clear a couple cells in row Z and then filter column Z to remove zeros.  I am very new to VBA so please excuse the ugly code.

The macro I have will work to separate and save the files, but I keep getting error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

I have been searching for other posts for hours and still can't figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Table of Contents")
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim FolderName As String
    Dim filterRow As Integer




    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    'Create new folder to save the new files in
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    FolderName = Sourcewb.Path & "\" & "Department Expenses - Split"
    MkDir FolderName

    'Copy every visible sheet to a new workbook
    For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets
        filterRow = sh.Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row 'This is the line giving me problems
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
        Range("Z9").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("Z12").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("Z14").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("Z77").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("Z100").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        sh.Range(filterRow).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<>0"
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `x1Up` - You are looking for `xlUp`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this first open the workbook in the folder you want to copy the sheets and than do the edit and filter after save each worksheet in the same folder where you open the workbook. You were getting the error because you were not qualifying `Rows.Count` needs to be `sh.Rows.Count` so it know from what sheet it's counting.

```
    Sub CopySheetsToNewWorkbook()

    Dim xPath As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim filterRow As Integer
    Dim questionBoxPopUp As VbMsgBoxResult

     questionBoxPopUp = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to copy each worksheets as a new workbook in the current folder?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, "Copy Worksheets?")
        If questionBoxPopUp = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   For Each sh In Sourcewb.Worksheets
        filterRow = sh.Range("Z" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'not too sure why you need this
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
        Range("Z9").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("Z12").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("Z14").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("Z77").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("Z100").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        sh.Range("Z" & filterRow).AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:="<>0" 'Change column "Z" to suit your needs. I think you need jut the header range to filter it.

    For Each xWs In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        xWs.Copy
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name & ".xlsx"
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next xWs

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Process completed!", vbInformation

     Exit Sub '<--- exit here if no error occured
    ErrorHandler:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
            MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbCrLf & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I learned a lot from just reading what you put together.  However, when I tried running your code, I got an error saying "424 Object required.  I tried adding `Dim sh As Worksheet` but I am still getting that error.  I feel like I'm missing something relatively simple syntax-wise.  Any suggestions on troubleshooting?

Comment: Have ‘Option explicit’ at top of your module also ad ‘dim sh as worksheet’

Comment: I haven’t tested it and it would seem that I’ve missed a few things but it should help you get on the right path just check all variables declared and also see if I set them ex I can see now I have not set sh = worksheet

Comment: I added Option Explicit and `Dim sh As Worksheet` but now it says "Compile error:  Invalid inside procedure"  on the Option Explicit line

Comment: @JonSnowNothing option explicit will be one thine at the top of the module.